# App not detected on startup

Tags: boot, brave

When I start up my system, twice now it hasn't detected brave browser, which I have previously installed, used and locked to my favourites bar.

Previously when this happened, I restarted and it was there. This time when I restarted, still no brave browser. When I search for "brave", nothing comes up.

Just as I write this, my favourites bar updated and brave browser is now there and also present when I search "brave".

Can anyone tell me what's happening and how I can prevent this from happening in the future?

Thank you.

Comment: Some details on your Ubuntu version, on the desktop environment you use and on how you installed the browser will be usefull. Add to your question: use "Edit"

Comment: I'm a windows user usually so I'm not totally clear on what details you're referring to or where to find them. If I go to "About" in settings:
OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
GNOME version: 3.36.8
Windowing System: x11

I'm pretty sure all my installations have been debian? Though I'm sure I just googled brave browser download ubuntu and followed from there.

Comment: That is the needed info indeed. For installation: you did not use "Snap store", but some manual install using a downloaded `.deb` installation file apparently.